# What's allowed in the header of a for loop?

Tags: c#, loops

In C#, I've seen some strange and complex logic in the headers of loops.

What is/isn't possible in the header of a for loop? Is it possible to have more than one incrementor/variable?

Thanks

Comment: have you consider reading the language definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to have more than one incrementor/variable?

Yes, it is possible. That is, this is perfectly legal:

```
// reverse b into a
for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j--) {
    a[i] = b[j]
}
```

> What is/isn't possible in the header of a `for` loop?

That is exactly what the grammar will tell you. Here is the grammar for a `for` statement in C#:

```
for-statement:
    for(for-initializer_opt; for-condition_opt; for-iterator_opt)
        embedded-statement
for-initializer:
    local-variable-declaration
    statement-expression-list
for-condition:
    boolean-expression
for-iterator:
    statement-expression-list
statement-expression-list:
    statement-expression
    statement-expression-list, statement-expression
```

Note that both the `for-initializer` and the `for-iterator` allow compound statements via `statement-expression-list`. See §8.8.3 of the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdfv) for addtional details. You'll probably also want to visit §8.5.1 of the specification for exactly what `local-variable-declaration` entails (hint: `int i = 0, j = n - 1, k = 42` is legal but `int i = 0, j = n - 1, long k = 42` is not).

Comment: as long as all of the items are one type, you can do a LOT of declarations and initializations.

Answer (score 2):

The [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

[C# Language Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx)